# I am trying to open a nested subscreen using an intent but everytime I do that the app crashes. What is the reason for it?

Tags: android, android-settings

My nested subscreen inside an xml filename looks like this

My headersActivity code

```
 public class HeadersActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.language);
}
```

}

My settingsActivity code:

```
  public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

}

public static class ChatSettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.finish();
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please post error logs?

Comment: error log:  11-17 19:09:03.360: I/QCNEJ(782): |CORE:COM:RCVR| CNE creating socket
11-17 19:09:03.410: W/ActivityManager(782): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41db67a8 u0 org.fossasia.susi.ai/.activities.SettingsActivity}
11-17 19:09:04.411: W/QCNEJ(782): |CORE| mDefaultApnLinkProp is null

Comment: As per your error log I think there is a long operation performed in your activity onPause() life cycle method.

Comment: So what should I do to solve this issue?